# OpenGL perspective overlay on ortho

Tags: opengl, textures, perspective, orthographic

I have set the background texture with Ortho bounds.I have some drawings in perspective which are required to be overlaid on top of this.

Why the foreground Object in perspective cannot be seen?

```
void handleResize(int w, int h)
    {
        width=w;
        height=h;
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45.0, (float)w / (float)h, 1.0, 200.0);
    }
    void Draw2D()
    {     
        //ORTHO
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0.0f, 1024.0, 0.0, 512.0, 0.0, 1.f);

         glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureId);

        //Bottom
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glBegin (GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(0.0,0.0);
        glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(1024.0,0.0);
        glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(1024.0,512.0);
        glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(0.0,512.0);
        glEnd();    
    }
    void Draw3D()
    {    
        //PERSPECTIVE
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45.0, (float)width / (float)height, 1.0, 200.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();           
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);            
        glutWireCube(0.5);      
    }
    void drawScene()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);             
        Draw3D();
        Draw2D();           
        glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

@Matso..I am using below function for the depth testing

```
void initRendering() 
{
    //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);//Comment this
    glDepthMask(false);//Use this
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);    
    Image* image = loadBMP("earth.bmp");
    _textureId = loadTexture(image);
    delete image;
}
```

Introducing

```
glDepthMask(false);
```

did the trick.I am able to view my perspective drawings.

Comment: How do You set up depth test for the texture? I can't see anything in that regard.

Comment: you may prevent depth write with: `glDepthMask(false)` while rendering the ui quad. Ensure your ui texture alpha is 0 where nothing is drawn. blending should be enabled, or discard (the ui texture) yourself in fragment shader when alpha=0, I think alpha testing should do the trick too. (so 3 possible solutions)

Comment: @j-p ,Excellent ..first trick worked for me !